# Haskell: Why does this function keep asking for user input and not terminating

Tags: haskell

I'm learning some Haskell and I came across this small program

```
reverseLines :: String -> String
reverseLines input = 
    unlines (map reverse (lines input))

main :: IO ()
main = interact reverseLines
```

This program will keep asking the user for more input and reverse the input and print it on the screen.

Most of this is straight forward but one thing I can't wrap my head around is why does this function keeps running and ask the user for more input whereas if I just replace the `reverseLines` function with a function the simply returns some string it will not happen.

This program will stop after one execution:

```
foo input = "Stops"
main :: IO ()
main = interact foo
```

Why?

Comment: it works in your case because `String` is lazy and the `lines`/`unlines` splits the input into nice parts - it's indeed almost magical :D

Comment: Ok, I Think I got it.  Guess this is part of the confusing parts in Haskell when coming from traditional imperative / semi-functional languages. Thanks!

Comment: (btw: on Linux you can enter the EOF yourself with CTRL-D)

Comment: @Carsten Yep - that what stops the first program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [source of `interact`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/System.IO.html#interact) you see this:

```
interact f      =   do s <- getContents
                       putStr (f s)
```

see the `getContents`? This is where the magic starts - it will read everything till **EOF**

Now in Haskell this is *lazy-IO* which can be bad but here is almost magical - see the string is read lazily and passed to your `reverseLines` - this one of course will only generate output as soon as it saw `\n` characters (the `lines`) and so it seems your program is some kind of REPL.

In the second one you don't consume any of the lazy-string at all so it stops ASAP

As I wrote in the comments you can play with this by either passing content into the program using a file (or `echo`) and pipes on the terminal:

```
echo "Hello World\nBye Bye" | runhaskell LazyIO.hs
```

or using CTRL-D to pass in the EOF yourself.

To get a feeling for it I would play with the functions more - what happens if you use something that needs to see the complete input first (try `reverse` without the maps)? What happens with `words` instead of `lines`, ...?

Have fun!

Comment: Perfect. Going to play a little bit with those ideas.

Comment: you might have a strange moment with the `words` test (it will probably wait till `\n` too) - if so use `hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering` to disable the input buffering (all in `System.IO`) and it should work at spaces ;)